# Call to undefined method stdClass::delete()

Tags: laravel

First I make a connection with the CMS trouw API the store method works fine but the update and the delete gives my error undefined method.

If I dd `$basket` in the delete I get all the data out which means it works fine for the `delete` method but unfortunately doesn't work, any suggestions.

```
public function add(Request $request)
{
    $productId = $request->get('id');
    $amount = $request->get('amount');

    $this->basketService->add($productId, $amount);

    return redirect()->route('basket.index');
}

public function update(Request $request)
{
    foreach ($request->get('amount') as $key => $amount) {
        $this->basketService->update($key, $amount);
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}

public function delete($id)
{
    $basket = $this->basketService->getCart();
    $basket->delete($id);
    return redirect()->route('basket.index');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends which methods are in basketService Class.
Show source code basketService Class.
(Possible you need call method so: $this->basketService->delete();)

Comment: public function remove($id)
        {
           $shoppingCart= $this->loadShoppingCart();

            if (isset($shoppingCart[$id])) {
                unset($shoppingCart[$id]);
            }

            return ('basket-called to add ' . $id);
        }

Comment: $this->basketService->remove($id);